# Restrict input with pattern

Tags: javascript

I want to take input from user as their name in text field.  I want to do this using two expressions:

```
  pattern="[/\D/gi]"
  // and
  pattern="[/\s/gi]"
```

but it takes input without space. I want to take input with a space included.

Comment: doesn't `\D` include space characters

Comment: Why do you want to use two regexes?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1171/ obligatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**
It is not allowed any space before any name  and also allowed after name

```html
<input name="userName" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$" required />
```

**explantion**

```
     ^  //start of the string
    [a-zA-Z]  //first char must be a letter (lowercase & uppercase)
    [a-zA-Z\s]+  //and 2nd char - more then one  must be letter (lowercase & uppercase) and space
    $  //end of the string.
```

Comment: Thanks buddy..it worked..will you please describe how it worked?

Comment: Go to this [link](https://regex101.com/#javascript) and put this code `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+` in **Regular Expression** field and see explanation from the right side by click.

Comment: I can,t understand from there buddy..Will you please describe it for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex: `[a-zA-Z ]+`

```
<input name="userName" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" />
```

Check out [this site](http://html5pattern.com/), you could find it useful for future validations.